# 8086 doesn't write to external memory

Tags: assembly, x86

we are working on a circuit containing a 8086 and 8x(2KB) external memories (6116). the problem is that all control signals are asserted correctly, the address and data is provided but they are not written to the memory.

On StackOverflow: [8086 can't access to external memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643424/8086-cant-access-to-external-memory)

[image: schematic]

[original](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eznyj0pQfS2ccj5eIesYnnle01v2ftId)

Comment: The question should be self-contained. I.e. no external links to the critical information.

Comment: bypass capacitors on the several rails? overshoots on the signals (use a 1GHz probe and scope to find the 1nanoSecond overshoots)? GND planes to prevent noise-margin violations?

Comment: Why does every memory chip have its own data bus buffer?

Comment: _"all control signals are asserted correctly, the address and data is provided but they are not written to the memory."_ - how do you know the data isn't written to the memory?